# encoded string has 3 dot(...)

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

When i converting my bitmap to string using base64, got the result with 3 dots at the end of the string. why does it happen? 
my base64 code is given below

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
    byte[]imagedata= baos.toByteArray();
    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imagedata, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the string i got is

```
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...
```

Comment: it shows its going on..it show only visible part in logcat

Comment: @lmtiyaz i need to pass the string to a webservice then i got the error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: are you sending via post or get?

Comment: via post and using json

Comment: then check entire json,you will find problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i got the solution. The string contain full characters,the logcat shows only a part of the string,thats why it showing s dots(...) at the end

Answer (score 0):

there are no any dot at the end its just indicate there are more string below. if you want to show complete String then take one Scrollview and inside it take Textview. and Show your String in TextView instead of logcat. Now you can see complete text of your Bitmap.

thats it...

Comment: i need to pass the string to a webservice then i got the error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("bmp", encodedImage);
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,7000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 7000);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Constants.SavePhoto);
request.setEntity(newByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));request.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: ok encodedImage.replace("+","-").replace("_","/"); try this code.. then after replace send String to server